# PHP/SQL comet using jQuery without flooding the database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, comet

I am figuring out how comet works with PHP and jQuery, now I got it to work with a file and modify date. But how do I do this properly with SQL without completely flooding my database?

My file comet:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    $file = "file.txt";
    $last = filemtime($file);
    $current = time();
    
    while($current >= $last) {
        usleep(10000);
        clearstatcache();
        $last = filemtime($file);
    }

echo "YES";
```

jQuery:

```
function wait() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "get.php",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            wait();
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    wait();
});
```

Now, with the file this works fine, but with SQL I would assume I need to do a `SELECT` query every single time it loops in the while, which will be too much requests to the server.

**I am not asking for code, I am asking for someones vision on how to do it with minimizing server load.**

## Edit:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "kleurmixer") or die (mysqli_error());
    $sql = "SELECT hue FROM tags";
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    $assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $current = $assoc['hue'];
    $last = $assoc['hue'];
    
    while(true) {
        $sql = "SELECT hue FROM tags";
        $sql = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
        $assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $last = $assoc['hue'];
        if($current != $last) {
            echo $last;
            return true;
        } else {
            sleep(5);
        }
    }
```

I got this far, but this still does a request to the database every 5 seconds. Now, this isn't a huge problem for my application because it will be used by 1-5 people at max (private webserver), but I still like to minimize the server load. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need a loop, you need an event driven solution.

Comment: Do you by any chance have any documentation on what you mean? A link to a website guide or something

Comment: What I mean is: You have to have a system, which tells your comet server, that something has changed and what he has to do. That will be difficult with MySQL because MySQL itself has no external events. For a similar approach I use CouchDB and PouchDB.